# How can I output the current iteration with Laravel's Paginate()?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

Laravel 5.2 application.

I have a function in my controller that queries my DB with an order by clause to which I then paginate.

```
public function foo() {

  $results = DB::orderBy('name', 'desc')->paginate(15);
  return view('index', ['results' => $results]);

}
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($results as $result)
 <tr>
  <td>{{ //current $result position is what I need }}</td>
  <td>{{ $result->name }}<td>
  //etc...
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

How could I output the current row order iteration?

e.g.

```
Rank | name | //page 1
1      bob  
2      john
3      katie
Rank | name | //page 2
4      dave  
5      michael
6      ruben
```

Usually I would just output the `id` but since I have an orderBy clause, the ID won't correctly reflect the current rank. And if I do something like a `for()` loop then when I go to the next page, it will reset the first result on the second page, to rank 1, even though it's the next page.

Does Laravel have a specific way of achieving this? I've looked through the docs and I'm unable to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to do this more elegantly than the suggestions provided via the `firstItem()` method.

```
public function foo() {

  $results = DB::orderBy('name', 'desc')->paginate(15);

  $rank = $results->firstItem();

  return view('index', ['rank' => $rank, 'players' => $players]);

}


index.blade.php

@foreach ($results as $result)
 <tr>
  <td>{{ $rank++ }}</td>
  <td>{{ $result->name }}<td>
  //etc...
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get a first row number of the current page:

```
$firstRowOnThisPage = $results->currentPage() * $results->perPage() - $results->perPage() + 1;
```

And then use this variable in a simple `@for` loop or just do `$i++` in a `@foreach` loop.

Comment: If I could I'd upvote this a thousand times, this works brilliantly.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
@foreach ($results as $index => $result)
 <tr>
  <td>{{ (Input::get('page', 1) - 1) * $results->getPerPage() + $index + 1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ $result->name }}<td>
  //etc...
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

This will only work if your using the `?page=` in your url. If that doesn't work you can inject that variable in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I´d give the additional helpers a try:

**https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination > Additional Helper Methods**

```
$result->currentPage()
```

With this method you can surely achieve what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

my solution is

```
<td>{{$customer->currentPage() * $customer->perPage() - $customer->perPage() + 1 +$loop->index}}</td>
```

its work for me

Answer (score 0):

@foreach ($results as $index => $result)
{{ (Input::get('page', 1) - 1) * $results->firstItem() + $index }} {{ $result->name }} //etc... @endforeach

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).